# json nested output from joining data from 2 google sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets, nested

Here is the scenerio:

i have 2 google sheets that have related data

Orders

| OrderNum | CustName |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | Cust 1 |
| 1001 | Cust 2 |

Details

| OrderNum | ItemNum | SerNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Item 1 | 12345 |
| 1000 | Item 2 | 23456 |
| 1000 | Item 3 | 34567 |
| 1001 | Item 1 | 45678 |
| 1001 | Item 2 | 56789 |

I need to output to a JSON file that looks like this - I will need to transmit this file to to an API via curl or similar method.  Help... I am a total newb to this and am looking for guidance...

```
{
 "Orders" : [
{
  "CustName" : "Cust 1",
  "OrderNum" : "1000",
 
  "Items" : [
    {
      "ItemNum" : "Item1",
      "SerNum" : "12345",
      "task_id" : 0
    },
    {
      "ItemNum" : "Item2",
      "SerNum" : "23456",
      "task_id" : 1
    },
    {
      "ItemNum" : "Item3",
      "SerNum" : "34567",
      "task_id" : 2
    ],
     },
   {
  "CustName" : "Cust 2",
  "OrderNum" : "1001",
 
  "Items" : [
    {
      "ItemNum" : "Item1",
      "SerNum" : "45678",
      "task_id" : 0
    },
    {
    {
      "ItemNum" : "Item2",
      "SerNum" : "56789",
      "task_id" : 1
    ],
     }
```

Thanks for help...

Since I am new to this I did not even know where to start...
Data is in google sheets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about using a Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and please set the sheet names. And, run the function. By this, you can see the result values in the log.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName1 = "Orders";
  const sheetName2 = "Details";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName1);
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName2);
  const values1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:B" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const values2 = sheet2.getRange("A2:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const obj2 = values2.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => {
    const temp = { "ItemNum": b, "SerNum": c, "task_id": o[a] ? o[a].length : 0 };
    return Object.assign(o, { [a]: (o[a] ? [...o[a], temp] : [temp]) });
  }, {});
  const res = {
    "Orders": values1.reduce((ar, [a, b]) => {
      if (obj2[a]) {
        ar.push({ "CustName": b, "OrderNum": a, "Items": obj2[a] });
      }
      return ar;
    }, [])
  };
  console.log(res);
}
```

- When this script is run using your provided sample tables, the value of `res` is as follows.

  ```json
  {
     "Orders":[
        {
           "CustName":"Cust 1",
           "OrderNum":1000,
           "Items":[
              {
                 "ItemNum":"Item 1",
                 "SerNum":12345,
                 "task_id":0
              },
              {
                 "ItemNum":"Item 2",
                 "SerNum":23456,
                 "task_id":1
              },
              {
                 "ItemNum":"Item 3",
                 "SerNum":34567,
                 "task_id":2
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "CustName":"Cust 2",
           "OrderNum":1001,
           "Items":[
              {
                 "ItemNum":"Item 1",
                 "SerNum":45678,
                 "task_id":0
              },
              {
                 "ItemNum":"Item 2",
                 "SerNum":56789,
                 "task_id":1
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- If you want to use this script as a custom function, please use the following script. In this case, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE(Orders!A2:B, Details!A2:C)` to a cell.

  ```js
  function SAMPLE(values1, values2) {
    const obj2 = values2.reduce((o, [a, b, c]) => {
      if (a && b && c) {
        const temp = { "ItemNum": b, "SerNum": c, "task_id": o[a] ? o[a].length : 0 };
        return Object.assign(o, { [a]: (o[a] ? [...o[a], temp] : [temp]) });
      }
      return o;
    }, {});
    const res = {
      "Orders": values1.reduce((ar, [a, b]) => {
        if (obj2[a]) {
          ar.push({ "CustName": b, "OrderNum": a, "Items": obj2[a] });
        }
        return ar;
      }, [])
    };
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: not sure what i am screwing up here but this is what the log shows.  
 3:07:47 PM Info { Orders: 
   [ { CustName: 'Cust 1', OrderNum: 1000, Items: [Object] },
     { CustName: 'Cust 2', OrderNum: 1001, Items: [Object] },
     { CustName: 'Cust 3', OrderNum: 1002, Items: [Object] } ] }

Comment: @Darren Wachtell Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that my proposed script works fine as JSON object. If you want to retrieve it as the string value, please modify `console.log(res);` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));` and test it again.

Comment: thank you so much...you are so fabulously helpful!!

Comment: thank you that works. i wanted to create a button in the spreadsheet to do something like the following Sample CURL Command
curl ‐X POST ‐k ‐H 'Content‐Type: application/json' ‐H 'apikey: 6e5e63df‐bb37‐4871‐b3cf‐9ab7720cf108' ‐i ' https://apidev.fdnycloud.org/api/cof/vendor/addhoodjobexternal ' ‐‐data '{
"License":"999W",
"ApiKey":"6e5e63df‐bb37‐4871‐b3cf‐9ab7720cf108"
}'
<then insert the json here we created from your code> and then post json, then display or save the response from the api...does that make sense? basically need to feed the data to the api from the sheet in json format

Comment: @Darren Wachtell Thank you for replying. About `thank you so much...you are so fabulously helpful!!` and `thank you that works.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer